# SQL Rotating numbers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I want to create a rotating logic in sql like consider there are 3 numbers 1,2,3 then first week 1,2 will be selected next 3,1 next 2,3 and so on..... if there are 4 numbers 1,2,3,4 then 1,2  next 3,4 next  1,2  so on... Like that i want to generate the numbers in sql server.Please help me.

Comment: I can't see a common pattern in your examples. Please check them again and give a complete list of what you want (don't use "and so on").

Comment: I think the pattern is to pick two numbers each week and loop around. So if three numbers you have 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,... "rotated" as follows: (1,2), (3,1), (2,3), ...; With 4 numbers: 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,... as (1,2), (3,4), (1,2), ...  So it's more like picking the next pair each week.

Answer (score 1):

You do like this:

```
declare @cnt int, @ofs int

select @cnt = count(*) from TheTable

set @ofs = (((@week - 1) * 2) % @cnt) + 1

select * from TheTable
where Number between @ofs and @ofs + 1
union all
select * from TheTable
where Number between @ofs - @cnt and @ofs - @cnt + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the modulus of the number of weeks since your epoch date, then select all the entries from a numbers table that are between 1 and your limit except the modulus result.